# How to help players find friends in a cross-platform mobile game?

Tags: cross-platform, facebook, social, pvp

Users on different platforms (iOS and Android) that play the game should be able to find each other and become friends in the game. They must have the possibility to invite other friends as well.
The game is PvP so they will also be able to fight one another.

Is Facebook the best way to go about it? (invitation sent by email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four major social sites: Facebook, G+, Twitter, and Pinterest are all great for this kind of thing. I would also look into using their email contacts.

But please, ensure you ask your players before you do anything with any info they give you, and don't excessively spam people. It's bad for your game, people's sanity, and the industry as a whole.

Comment: So, using social platforms is better than say, using open feint?

Comment: I won't spam them. :) Their data is used strictly to help them find friends.

Comment: Personally, I hate open feint. Sure it's easy to implement (in some cases), but it bloats your game, functions horribly or not at all when the player has low or no service, adds a lot of features you'll likely never use, and they sell user data (or so I've read).

Comment: Ok, open feint is off the table then. The last thing i need is for my users to have their data leaked. I'll go with Facebook for a start. Thank you.